# Write karate gatling data to different databases listening to different ports using influx config

Tags: grafana, influxdb, karate

I want to write gatling performance data to different ports or to the databases because I have multiple microservices.
Below is my galting config file-

```
  graphite {
  light = false              # only send the all* stats
  host = "localhost"         # The host where the Carbon server is located
  port = 2003                # The port to which the Carbon server listens to (2003 is default for plaintext, 2004 is default for pickle)
  protocol = "tcp"           # The protocol used to send data to Carbon (currently supported : "tcp", "udp")
  rootPathPrefix = "offeringqualification" # The common prefix of all metrics sent to Graphite
  bufferSize = 8192          # Internal data buffer size, in bytes
  writePeriod = 1            # Write period, in seconds
} #I have wrapped this content inside gatling scope
```

Below is my influxdb conf-

```
###[[graphite]]
  enabled = true
  database = "offeringqualification"
  retention-policy = ""
  bind-address = ":2003"
  protocol = "tcp"
  consistency-level = "one"
  # Flush if this many points get buffered
  batch-size = 50000
```

I have tried changing the ports in influx db and configuring 2 graphite listeners, but gatling always tries to send to 2003 port even if I update the gatling conf file to different port. Tried adding different templates in influx still gatling follows the default gatling template in writing data. I want to write different data to different databases based on which project i am working on. Also, dont want multiple influx database instances running at the same time.

Comment: not my area of expertise, but maybe your conf file is not in the classpath. if you used karate's convention, it may need to be in `src/test/java`

Comment: Yes, using karate convention and it's in src/test. Looks like it's working now. I restarted influxdb and with the same config it's working. Although, I had already restarted once after changing the configuration.