# Karate Dsl integration with InfluxDb and grafana to share test metrics

Tags: karate

I am a beginner in Karate and I need some help in integrating karate with Influx Db and grafana.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if this question helps you: [Write karate gatling data to different databases listening to different ports using influx config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60107645/143475)

Else you have to figure this out on your own, this is not something related to Karate.