# Karate gatling grafana integration - is it possible to write raw measurement data into influxDB?

Tags: grafana, karate, influxdb, gatling

I am a newbie in the Karate Gatling framework and trying to exchange current solution (Newman based) with KarateDSL + InfluxDB + Grafana.
What I've noticed, that the measurements data, which is being written in the InfluxDB is already aggregated and contains:

- max, min, mean, percentiles50, percentiles75, etc. values.

It makes it not possible to display the actual graph in Grafana, as the values do not make sense anymore. Is it possible to write the raw measurements data in the InfluxDB (or any other DB) to be able to display the proper graph?
[image: InfluxDB Table]
[image: Grafana Graph]

Thanks in advance

I was trying to find a setting which would allow to write the raw measures in the DB, but could not find it.
I would expect it should be possible to build such a graphical representation of the performance test results: [image: Expected Grafana graph]

Comment: you can see someone got it working here (see comments): https://stackoverflow.com/q/60107645/143475 - otherwise I have no idea and this is not "core" to karate. I suggest you post back what worked for you and do some research if needed